# notepad ++ add character to space between characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to add a dash between words that currently have a blank space, ie

> this is a test
>
> becomes
>
> this-is-a-test

I know that it mostly likely would require regex, but not sure how to format it in notepad ++

Comment: why don't you just replace spaces by dashes ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem with replacing all spaces is that it would add dashes to areas in my file with spaces that have numbers instead of non numeric characters.

Comment: @rahrahruby please add an example of that to your question.

Comment: @rahrahruby, Did you like either of the answers?  Please choose one.  :^)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds to check those conditions, e.g. by

```
(?<=[A-Za-z]) (?=[A-Za-z])
```

And then simply replace it with `-`. If multiple consectuive spaces have to be considered, you can also use  `+`. If you also consider tabs, you can use `\h` to match all kinds of horizontal whitespaces.

If you have to consider all unicode letters, use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`.

If you want to do the replacing by using single replace operations instead of using replace all, you will have to turn one of the lookarounds into a capturing group - e.g `([A-Za-z]) (?=[A-Za-z])` and replace by `\1-`.

Comment: This does not, however, properly replace the spaces in Notepad++   Hmmm.

Comment: @marklark It does work for me, though I have to admit that I lazily didn't update my NP++ for a while. Any specific string it doesn't work for?

Comment: I'm seeing that it does successfully find matches, but it doesn't do the replacement.

Comment: The single replace doesn't work, but 'Replace All' works incorrectly.  More in a moment.

Comment: Ah!  Because of the look-behind, the replacement string is '\2-\1'.  It still only works for 'Replace All'

Comment: @marklark I love NP++ bugs. Also covered in the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

in NotePad++'s Replace dialog,

Find what:  `(.)\b \b` (captured character, word boundary, a single space, a word boundary)

Replace with:  `\1-` (put character back, replace space by hyphen)

This now works for both 'Replace' and 'Replace All'.

Comment: This will however not work properly for single character words in the middle of a sentence - `Am I Groot?`